# Cartoon from the '80s/early '90s about a huge robot that flies through space and had a train behind him with people/children that he saved

Tags: story-identification, space, robots, animation

I'm trying to find the name of an cartoon/anime from the '80s, maybe '90s. I remember there was a huge, friendly robot that in one scene flies through space and, instead of legs, he had like a train behind him with people/children that he saved.

I also remember that he had number 7 written on his belt buckle and that he crashed in some wasteland where he gets covered in snow and is awakened by some people so he could help win the war.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the anime, ***[Super Express Mazinger 7](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3252/Super_Express_Mazinger_7)*** (1983), also known by the alternate title of *[Protectors of Universe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0933763/)*.

From a [review](https://www.animeherald.com/2013/09/22/bad-anime-night-needs-protectors-universe/):

> *Protectors of Universe* is a 75-minute film by IFD Films & Arts Limited. The film is set in a distant future, where war is erupting. The kingdom of the New Star has been overtaken by vicious bionic human Alfred, whose sole ambition is to conquer the universe. Alfred’s first target the capital city of peaceful planet Orion. Kanann, king of the city, find his troops to be useless against Alfred’s onslaught. **In an act of desperation, Kanaan sends his son Prince Cifrian, his daughter Susan, and a hell of a lot of random children to Earth, in the middle of a battlefield, on a gigantic intergalactic train** with no weapons, and no means of real defense.

A giant robot with the number '7' on its 'belt buckle' is briefly shown flying through space at around the 0:30 mark in the trailer below, and you can see a train extending from beneath its waist in the last few seconds of the video.

I checked the full movie on YouTube, and there is a scene [about halfway through](https://youtu.be/eQg_8UsjVtc?t=2047) where the robot crashes down on a snow-covered landscape. The train section of the robot is also shown to be full of children, as per the bolded text in the review quoted above.

Comment: Yepp, this is the one! I was looking for this cartoon for like 20 years.